# Correct way to type strings with parenthesis in them?

Tags: typing

I have a question regarding typing technique. I learned how to type in school, and I type enough that I do occasionally get some wrist fatigue, and when I switch back to the specific techniques I learned in school, my wrists feel better. Specifically, I mean the idea of performing keystrokes like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LETTER</kbd> using two hands rather than the same hand.

Example: I wanna type `Linux`, so I use my left pinky on <kbd>shift</kbd> + right pinky on <kbd>L</kbd>, rather than R pinky on <kbd>shift</kbd> and R pointer on <kbd>L</kbd>.

I often find myself typing strings of parentheses, such as `part (a)` or html tags like

```
<i> wow </i>
```

for which it is very easy to **NOT** follow the strict typing rules, but appears detrimental to my wrists. So my question is if there are specific patterns used in professional typing which I can employ, or if I just need to work out and practice these patterns using the usual alternating approach.

Comment: http://productivity.stackexchange.com seems to be a better fit for ergonomics related queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.typing-lessons.org/lesson_4.html) a link to a typing lesson covering shift usage. There are many more typing lessons on the site, but that particular one covers shift usage.

It would seem that your assumption is correct: you use the opposite pinky for the shift every time, so for parenthesis you would always be using your left pinky.

Comment: That's a great website - there are specific lessons targeting exactly what I was talking about, and it would seem that you are correct - the shift rule rules all. Thanks!